# multiple images are being displayed on click instead of one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

i have been having trouble getting this to work every time i try to change the image multiple images appear multiplied i want to be able to display one image at a time and if i want i can click the image so the image appears again basically. also i want to use draggable and resizable on each image

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
  $('.subselector').on('change', function() {
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
 
 $('#dog').on('change', function() {
  $("#lrgdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'smalldog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});

 $('#dog').on('change', function() {
  $("#smdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'largedog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
  
 

  $('img').on('click', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#fotos').append('<img class="modal-content" src="' + src + '">');
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div id="fotos" ><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div>


<select id="imajes">
  <option value="">Choose Image</option>
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
</select>


<select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="smalldog">small dog</option>
  <option value="largedog">Large Dog</option>
</select>


<select id="cat" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="smallcat">small cat</option>
</select>

  
<div style='display:none;' id="lrgdogimges" class="smallimages">
  <div data-image="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
  <div data-image="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/lyellow.jpg">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/lyellow.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id="smdogimges" class="smallimages">
  <div data-image="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/wlsblack.jpg">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/wlsblack.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
  <div data-image="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
  
</div>

<div style='display:none;' id="catimges" class="smallimages">
  <div data-image="http://i.imgur.com/BHoIzPj.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BHoIzPj.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
</div>
```

just changing the image being displayed at one click to just one per click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have did something incorrect as follows,

```
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  $("#lrgdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'smalldog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});

 $('#dog').on('change', function() {
  $("#smdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'largedog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

You should only bind an event once.

```
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  $("#lrgdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'smalldog') ? 'block' : 'none');
  $("#smdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'largedog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Please move you following code out of `$('.subselector').on('change', function() {`
 method. It is binding `click` event multiple times hence the issue.

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src')+ '">');
});
```

Comment: sorry its not working how i wanted it to i want to be able to show an image per click if i click 5 times i want the image to show five times

Comment: then append is correct. Then what is the issue you face with append?

Comment: every time i change image the number of images per click multiply why is that happening

Comment: @xcalliber check my updated answer. You are binding click on each change event which causing it trigger multiple times.

Comment: sorry i didnt refresh

Comment: @xcalliber glad to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you wish to display only one photo at a time inside your `#fotos` container. For that, simply change the `.append()` function to `.html()` like:

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#fotos').html('<img class="modal-content" src="' + src + '">');
});
```

This will replace the `img` inside `#fotos` instead of inserting another one.

Comment: all its doing is replacing the photo with another one i want to keep the image and add more and add the same one multiple times

Comment: Then I do not understand what is it you want. Please update your question to better reflect your desired result.